# Text to Speech file is not working(Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I am trying to convert texts I've into Speech, using Google Text to Speech API, and code is working and getting saved in drive, but it's not playing, I am not sure why, I am using this API for the first time, can you point out what I am doing wrong here

```
 function textToSpeech() {
  // Set your API key here
  var apiKey = 'APIKEY';

  // Create a new UrlFetchApp service.
  var urlFetchApp = UrlFetchApp;

  // Set the endpoint URL.
  var endpointUrl = 'https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize?key=' + apiKey;

  // Create the request body.
  var requestBody = {
    'input': {
      'text': "This is the test"
    },
    'voice': {
      'languageCode': 'en-US',
      'name': 'en-US-Wavenet-B',
      'ssmlGender': 'MALE'
    },
    'audioConfig': {
      'audioEncoding': 'LINEAR16'
    }
  };

  // Make the request.
  var response = urlFetchApp.fetch(endpointUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
  });

  // Get the audio data.
  var audioData = response.getContent();

  // Save the audio data to a file.
  var audioBlob = Utilities.newBlob(audioData, 'audio/wav', 'output.wav');
  DriveApp.createFile(audioBlob);
}
```

I also tried using audioencoding as "MP3" but that is also not working

Answer (score 0):

When I saw the official document, it seems that the response value is a JSON data like `{"audioContent": "//NExAASCCIIAAhEAGAAEMW4kAYPnwwIKw/BBTpwTvB+IAxIfghUfW.."}`. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/create-audio-text-command-line)

In your script, the response value is directly used. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var audioData = response.getContent();
```

#### To:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var audioData = Utilities.base64Decode(obj.audioContent);
```

#### References:

- [Create audio from text by using the command line](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/create-audio-text-command-line)
- [base64Decode(encoded)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64decodeencoded)

Comment: @vector Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.